# SQL query with "not exists" not working

Tags: sql, where-clause, exists

I'm trying to use a simple query but I'm not getting anywhere.
The objective is to "learn" how "not exists" works.
I have a simple table with "idUsuario" as default ID for users and a name.

```
    SELECT * FROM usuario
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM usuario
        WHERE u.idUsuario =16
    )
```

Here i'm trying to get ALL the users from the table where the ID IS NOT 16. But it just get all of them.. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should join result from your query with result from the subquery as below

```
 SELECT * FROM usuario u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM usuario u1
        WHERE u1.idUsuario = u.idUsuario
        and u1.idUsuario =16
    )
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ae31/1/0)

Comment: Tried that, got no results. :(

Answer (score 3):

Parado's answer is correct.  I would add that a query with a single table does not provide the best demonstration of `NOT EXISTS`.  Usually your `NOT EXISTS` clause would reference another table.

For example, if you wanted to query the usuario table where the idUsuario value was not present in another table you would do:

```
 SELECT * FROM usuario u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM usuarioExclude x 
        WHERE x.idUsuario = u.idUsuario
    )
```

The usuarioExclude table could have any value(s) you wanted excluded from your results, such as 16 in your example.